# get real twitter username from twitter user id using swifter

Tags: ios, twitter, swift

I am trying to get the list of followers that a user s following on Twitter using `Swifter`. I managed to get the ids of the followers, but unable to get the real usernames. I am using the following the code to get the ids

```
self.swifter.getFriendsIDsWithScreenName("atifrasgeed", cursor: nil, stringifyIDs: true, count: nil, success: { (ids, previousCursor, nextCursor) -> Void in
            println(ids)
        }, failureHandler)
```

with this I manage to print the ids. Now I think I have to use the following method to get the real usernames from those ids

```
self.swifter.getUsersLookupWithUserIDs(ids, includeEntities: false, success: { (users) -> Void in

            }, failureHandler)
```

but now the problem is I cannot convert the ids from first method to `[String]` as the second method requires the ids to be in `[String]`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the resulting IDs which are delivered as JSONValue. Just use the string convert functionality of JSONValue.

for example you can convert the ids to an array of strings:

```
   var stringArray: [String]
   stringArray[]

   for id in ids{
      stringArray.append(id.string)
   }
```

For your example twitter account, I managed to get out the user names (just the first 4 here):
"The Batman"
"Cristiano Ronaldo"
"Jessica Hart"
"charlotte ronson"

Your original request fails, because you have too many user IDs for the call to getUsersLookupWithUserIDs(). Twitter allows only 100 each time.

Comment: yes , I managed to get it right. I used a different method though, but I got it working.